# Making side by side images move to vertical images on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, responsive-design

I have a div that features 4 side by side images, along with some text over the images. Rather than shrink the images and text when it's on mobile, I'd like to stack the images on top of each other. However, I'm stuck when I try to do it.

I played with the styles,and was never able to make this happen.

I created this JS Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/deadendstreet/pwrd78gv/) with some test images, however, only one image is showing up. This is not a problem on my website. Additionally, I pasted the styles below.

Thank you for your help.

```
#highlights {
width: 100%;
max-height: 200px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.89);
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
bottom: 200px;
}
#featured-boxes-light {
width: 100%;
max-height: 200px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03)
}
#highlights .swiper-slide {
position: relative;
cursor: pointer; 
}
#highlights .title-top, #featured-boxes .title-bottom {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
padding: 10px 20px 10px;
color: white;
font-size: 22px;
text-align: left;
/* margin-top: -36px; */
left: 0%;
/* margin-left: -35%; */
line-height: 22px;
bottom: 0px;
height: auto;
z-index: 1;
}
.swiper-wrapper {
max-height: 200px;
}
.fb-header {
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
font-weight: 600;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px black;
opacity: .9;
width: 25%;
}
.fb-title .title-top:hover {
opacity: .8 !important;
}
.fb-zoom {
max-width: 350px;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.fb-zoom img {
max-width: 350px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.fb-swipe-left, .fb-swipe-right {
height: 195px;
width: 40px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
z-index: 999;
background-size: contain !important;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s;
-o-transition: all 0.4s;
transition: all 0.4s;
cursor: pointer;
}
.fb-swipe-left:hover, .fb-swipe-right:hover {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
}
.fb-swipe-left {
background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-left-128.png") center center no-repeat rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
left: -40px;
}
.fb-swipe-left.fb-hovered {
left: 0;
}
.fb-swipe-right {
background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-right-128.png") center center no-repeat rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
right: -40px;
}
.fb-swipe-right.fb-hovered {
right: 0;
}
.swiper-scrollbar {
height: 5px;
position: absolute !important;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 999;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.14) !important;
}
.swiper-scrollbar-drag {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) !important;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/hon8trkz/

add this media query (width to be adjusted to your requirements):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px;) }
  .fb-zoom, .fb-zoom img {
    max-width: none;
    height: auto; 
  }
}
```

It sets the width of the images and their container to 100% on screens below 600px width. The `height: auto;` is optional - don't know if you want that.

Answer (score 2):

As @Johannes said, you can add a media query with a specific behavior to get the wanted result.

His query works fine, I just corrected your HTML structure for the last picture :

```
  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <a class="fb-title" href="">
      <div class="title-top">
        test                  </div>
      <div class="fb-zoom">
        <img width="400" height="224" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSkbgZKjIRwUafNM8Nbo5BwoaJWk7byZbD82LOqVAwku6jC1DM_Ig" class="attachment-small" alt="100 Songs from SXSW mixtape" />                     
      </div>
    </a><!--/.swiper-wrapper -->
  </div><!--/#swiper-featured -->
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pwrd78gv/4/)